# how to design Kafka Connect that is Sink as well as Source

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm developing a Kafka-Connector that subscribes to a topic, transforms messages, push the transformed messages back to another topic.

So far I'm implementing it as a `SinkTask` class, and each task performs the ETL, instantiate publisher object, write messages back to another topic.

Is there a cleaner way to implement it?  I believe this is a common use case that a connector is a sink as well as source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not the basic use case for Kafka Connect. If you are already on Kafka 0.10.x, the new [Kafka Streams API](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation#streams) was created exactly for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm stuck with older Kafka so I didn't notice Kafka Streams addressed the need.